# __init__ using method v lambda

Tags: python, methods, lambda, initialization, list-comprehension

When initializing an attribute in a class, is there a reason to avoid using a lambda expression or list comprehension, preferring a method or vice versa?

In example:
With

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
```

**List Comprehension**

```
class BarListComp():
    def __init__(self, listOfFoo):
        self.data = [fooInst.data for fooInst in listOfFoo if fooInst.data % 2 == 0]
```

**Lambda**

```
class BarLambda():
    def __init__(self, listOfFoo):
        self.data = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, map(lambda y: y.data, listOfFoo)))
```

**Method**

```
class BarMethod():

    def __init__(self, listOfFoo):
        self.data = self.genData(listOfFoo)

    @static_method
    def genData(listOfFoo):
        # this could also just be the earlier list comprehension
        listOut = []
        for elem in listOfFoo:
            if elem.data % 2 == 0:
                listOut.append(elem.data)
        return listOut
```

(Please note these might not be the greatest examples, and the needed processing could be much more complicated)

Is there a preferred method? Does an initialization process reach a suitable complexity to necessitate a new method to be split off?

Comment: My rule of thumb is: put yourself in the shoes of a reader who isn't familiar with the code, and do whatever you think they'll find the easiest to comprehend.

Comment: Your method `genData` should probably be a `@staticmethod` or a function outside of the class.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh You're right about static, updated

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @NPE comment (because I truly agree with his statement),

> is there a reason to avoid using a lambda expression or list comprehension, preferring a method or vice versa?

The answer is Yes and No.

My ambiguous answer is the consequence of the reality being, *choose wathever is more readable for you specific case*.

Now, opinion asides, for your above example I think it could be hardly arguable that your Lambda solution be favored. At a glance, it would be difficult to really get what is going on. So I'd say pick the method option or the list comprehension (which would be my GOTO solution).